# Custom Select Using Python

Tags: sql, python-3.x, select

I am using the below query :

```
sql = "SELECT ? FROM MyDB where Date between ? and ? and Name like ?",(age,fromdate,todate,(name) + '%')
```

I need to fetch only the parameterized column 'Age' from MyDB.
All the parameters (age,fromdate,todate,name) are provided as arguments.

The output shows :

> 'Age'
>
> 'Age'

The select is unable to resolve the 1st parameter. Rest all parameters are working as expected.
Any Suggestions!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand why "age" isn't a string but just a variable. Is this the issue ? If so you might need to type this :

```
sql = "SELECT %s FROM MyDB where Date between %s and %s and Name like %s"    %("age",fromdate,todate,name+'%')
```

Comment: Age is an argument which is passed to the script unlike others :   USAGE :             
python script.py age fromdate todate name.                                                                 The issue is that argument age is getting resolved as a string and thus instead of returning Age column from table, it simply return string : 'Age'.                                                                                          Hope this clarifies now.